# Ionic 5 variable Variable Interpolation is not working

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

I am trying to render a component variable in ionic 5, but its not being rendered in the view. The view is rendering perfectly, but when i try to use variable interpolation the hard-coded content also goes away.

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: "app-item-detail",
  templateUrl: "./item-detail.page.html",
  styleUrls: ["./item-detail.page.scss"]
})
export class ItemDetailPage implements OnInit {
  itemCount: number;

  constructor(
    private route: Router,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.itemCount = 1;
  }

  increaseItemCount() {
    if (this.itemCount >= 10) {
      this.itemCount = 10;
    } else {
      this.itemCount++;
    }
    console.log(this.itemCount);
  }
  decreaseItemCount() {
    if (this.itemCount <= 1) {
      this.itemCount = 1;
    } else {
      this.itemCount--;
    }
    console.log(this.itemCount);
  }

}
```

Here is my View code.

```
<ion-content class="bg-color">
  <ion-grid>
     <ion-row>
         <ion-col size="12">
             <div style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
                <h5 style="display: inline;margin-bottom: 0; margin-right:1em">
                  Quantity
                </h5>
                <ion-button (click)="decreaseItemCount()">
                  <ion-icon name="remove-outline"></ion-icon>
                </ion-button>
                <ion-content>{{itemCount}} Selected</ion-content>
                <ion-button (click)="increaseItemCount()">
                  <ion-icon name="add-outline"></ion-icon>
                </ion-button>
              </div>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

The view only i see is [image]

But it should show `1 Selected` also. On console it is showing, the `itemCount` variable is increasing or decreasing when button is pressed.

Comment: If you will check perfectely that `<ion-content>{{itemCount}} *Selected*</ion-content>` not only variable but, Your static word *`Selected`* is also not rendering. It means the issue is not in variable but I think issue is in `ion-content` tag. So check that perfectly.

Comment: @RohitTagadiya i tried with div and ion-input also but that also not interpolating the variable, its not only this variable which is causing issue if i try to use some other variable also it is also not interpolating.When the variable is rendered with hardcoded content it renders perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like ion-content inside an ion-content is the problem. Try replacing ion-content with div or something else. It works.

```
<div>{{itemCount}} Selected</div>
```

[image]

Comment: No that' not the issue, even i tried with div or any other ion elements also.

Comment: @Gaurav check the attached image

Comment: I am not sure what is causing issue in mine, i think ngx-translate might be causing i am not sure. I will check, and update the question asap.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue but failed to investigate the reason. So closing this for now, as your answer